# Prove the Cauchy Schwartz Inequality for Inner product spaces using Contradiction

Tags: proof-explanation, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Theorem: Let $H$ be an inner product space. Then $|⟨x,y⟩|≤⟨x,x⟩^{\frac{1}{2}}⟨y,y⟩^\frac{1}{2}$ for all $x,y∈H$ where equality holds if and only if x is a scalar multiple of $y$.

How do we prove this by contradiction?

I doubt that if x is not a scalar multiple of y, then this doesn't hold.

Suppose that x is not a scalar multiple of y, then what does that even mean?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do. Could you clarify further ?

Comment: Prove the theorem by contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to scaling, the usual approach is to define $z:=\langle y,\,y\rangle x-\langle y,\,x\rangle y$ so$$0\le\frac{\langle z,\,z\rangle}{\langle y,\,y\rangle}=\langle x,\,x\rangle\langle y,\,y\rangle-\langle x,\,y\rangle\langle y,\,x\rangle.$$If $x,\,y$ aren't parallel, $z\ne0\implies\langle z,\,z\rangle\ne0$, so the inequality is strict.

Comment: So, $$<z,z>=<\langle y,\,y\rangle x-\langle y,\,x\rangle y,\langle y,\,y\rangle x-\langle y,\,x\rangle y>?$$

Comment: @Muon3pi Now expand and simplify. The cross term is $-2$ times one of the diagonal terms. Bear in mind inner products are sesquilinear. BTW to get angle brackets use `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with bracket notation, is there a way to really understand it?

Comment: I know https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Sesquilinear_Form.

Comment: @Muon3pi $\langle x,\,y\rangle$ is just a fancy version of $x\cdot y$. We have linearity in one argument, $(\lambda x)\cdot y=\lambda(x\cdot y)$, plus antilinearity in the other, $x\cdot(\lambda y)=\lambda^\ast(x\cdot y)$. (Physicists tend to reverse that.)

Comment: Why do people sometimes use norm notation, and other times use bracket notation? How would you do this using norms?

Comment: @Muon3pi The [main motive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation#Bra-Ket_notation) of bra-ket notation is to think of dual space elements as vectors, and to treat the product as both a sesquilinear operator on the original space and a bilinear one relating it to its dual space. In particular, once we prove a few factors about dual space elements, we're able to show it makes sense to write $\langle x|y\rangle$ instead of $\langle x,\,y\rangle$.

Comment: $\langle z, z \rangle=(||y||^\frac{1}{2}x-\langle y, x \rangle y)^2$

Comment: @Muon3pi You don't need the $\tfrac12$. In fact, that exponent should be $2$.

Comment: I thought $\langle y, y \rangle=||y||^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: @Muon3pi If by $\Vert y\Vert$ you mean the length of $y$, what's actually true is $\Vert y\Vert=\langle y,\,y\rangle^{1/2}$. (If you mean the *squared* length, which is rarer, we don't need an exponent at all.)

Comment: $\langle z, z \rangle = (||y||x- \langle y, x \rangle y)^2=(||y||^2 x^2 - 2||y||x \langle y, x \rangle y + \langle y,x \rangle^2 y^2)$

Comment: $\frac{(||y||x- \langle y, x \rangle y)^2=(||y||^2 x^2 - 2||y||x \langle y, x \rangle y + \langle y,x \rangle^2 y^2)}{\langle y, y \rangle} = ||y||x^2-2x \langle y, x \rangle y + \langle y,x \rangle^2 y^2/||y|| $

Comment: @Muon3pi Your penultimate term needs to pair the $x$ & $y$. Also, count your powers of $\Vert y\Vert$ very carefully.